# JPA Spring -How to use criteria query on Object[] using spring jpa -Getting is not a Object[] or List

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, criteriaquery

How do i write criteria api for the below entity of type string-array

```
@Table(name = "Test")
     public class Test
    { 
        @Type(type = "string-array")
        @Column(name = "tempCol",columnDefinition = "text[]")
        public List<String> sampleColumnList;
    }
```

Query

```
//value={"abc,"def"}
private Predicate getPredicate(List<String> value,entityManager e) 
{
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SampleColumn> cq = cb.createQuery(SampleColumn.class);
Root<SampleColumn> root = cq.from(SampleColumn.class);

Object[] strArray1 = new Object[] {value};
Expression<Object[]> exp=root.get("tempCol");
Predicate predicate = cb.and(exp.in(strArray1));

cq.select(root).where(predicate);
TypedQuery<Test> tp = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
List<Test>c=tp.getResultList();
    }
```

I tried the above method but I am trying to query for records with abc, def as values from  tempCol

i keep getting the exception ***The provided abc is not Object[] or List!***,i tried with list instead of Object[] as well still didn't work.
What am I doing wrong

[Exception stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpOYr.png)